# How to calculate the time difference groupby ID between the min date and the date were values changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each unique ID, I want to calculate the time difference (in days) between their initial date (min(DATE)) and the date were their C1 is greater than their initial C1 OR their C2 is less than their initial C2. want to skip that ID's that has only one record and ID's that value doesn't change

```
ID      DATE                        C1 C2
AACH    2022-06-10 05:00:00+00:00   70  2
AAHA    2022-01-12 06:00:00+00:00   60  6
AAHA    2022-04-07 05:00:00+00:00   60  4
AAHA    2022-05-20 05:00:00+00:00   60  5
AALU    2021-09-10 05:00:00+00:00   70  0
AALU    2021-11-29 06:00:00+00:00   70  4
AALU    2022-05-17 05:00:00+00:00   60  5
ABAL    2021-10-11 05:00:00+00:00   60  0
ABAL    2022-03-17 05:00:00+00:00   80  4
ABAN    2021-05-24 05:00:00+00:00   60  3
ABAN    2021-06-24 05:00:00+00:00   70  2
ABAN    2021-08-10 05:00:00+00:00   60  3
ABAN    2022-01-14 06:00:00+00:00   70  2
ABAN    2022-03-18 05:00:00+00:00   60  5
ABAN    2022-04-21 05:00:00+00:00   70  2
```

My expected output is:

```
 ID     Time                        Difference(Days)   Date of value changed  
AAHA    2022-01-12 06:00:00+00:00   
AALU    2021-09-10 05:00:00+00:00   
ABAL    2021-10-11 05:00:00+00:00   
ABAN    2021-05-24 05:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

use dataframe sort_values and iloc

```
 txt="""ID,DATE,C1,C2
AACH,2022-06-10 05:00:00+00:00,70,2
AAHA,2022-01-12 06:00:00+00:00,60,6
AAHA,2022-04-07 05:00:00+00:00,60,4
AAHA,2022-05-20 05:00:00+00:00,60,5
AALU,2021-09-10 05:00:00+00:00,70,0
AALU,2021-11-29 06:00:00+00:00,70,4
AALU,2022-05-17 05:00:00+00:00,60,5
ABAL,2021-10-11 05:00:00+00:00,60,0
ABAL,2022-03-17 05:00:00+00:00,80,4
ABAN,2021-05-24 05:00:00+00:00,60,3
ABAN,2021-06-24 05:00:00+00:00,70,2
ABAN,2021-08-10 05:00:00+00:00,60,3
ABAN,2022-01-14 06:00:00+00:00,70,2
ABAN,2022-03-18 05:00:00+00:00,60,5
ABAN,2022-04-21 05:00:00+00:00,70,2"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep=',')

print(df.columns)
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','DATE'])

old_ID=""
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ID']!=old_ID:
        min_c1=df.iloc[index]['C1']
        min_c2=df.iloc[index]['C2']
       
    df.loc[index,'C1_GT_initC1']=df.iloc[index]['C1']>min_c1
    df.loc[index,'C2_LT_initC2']=df.iloc[index]['C2']<min_c2
    old_ID=row['ID']

print(df)
```

output:

```
    ID   DATE                       C1  C2 C1_GT_initC1 C2_LT_initC2
0   AACH 2022-06-10 05:00:00+00:00  70   2        False        False
1   AAHA 2022-01-12 06:00:00+00:00  60   6        False        False
2   AAHA 2022-04-07 05:00:00+00:00  60   4        False         True
3   AAHA 2022-05-20 05:00:00+00:00  60   5        False         True
4   AALU 2021-09-10 05:00:00+00:00  70   0        False        False
5   AALU 2021-11-29 06:00:00+00:00  70   4        False        False
6   AALU 2022-05-17 05:00:00+00:00  60   5        False        False
7   ABAL 2021-10-11 05:00:00+00:00  60   0        False        False
8   ABAL 2022-03-17 05:00:00+00:00  80   4         True        False
9   ABAN 2021-05-24 05:00:00+00:00  60   3        False        False
10  ABAN 2021-06-24 05:00:00+00:00  70   2         True         True
11  ABAN 2021-08-10 05:00:00+00:00  60   3        False        False
12  ABAN 2022-01-14 06:00:00+00:00  70   2         True         True
13  ABAN 2022-03-18 05:00:00+00:00  60   5        False        False
14  ABAN 2022-04-21 05:00:00+00:00  70   2         True         True
```

Comment: I want to group by ID so it can take the minimum value and compare those values with the same ID C1,C2 values. In the given solution, it compares the same C1, C2 values with all the ID's values. The initial values for each ID is different.